# Angular: ui-router link not working inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to put a ui-router link inside a directive "template".

Problem: Clicking on the link doesn't do anything.

```
.directive('hashfinder', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var content = $attrs.content;

      var html = content.replace(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig, function(match, p1, p2, offset) {
        var id = "r" + Math.random();

        // Here: ui-sref doesn't work.
        return p1 + '<a href="#" ui-sref="app.lounge" class="eva-hash-highlight2">' + p2 + '</a>';
      });
      $element.html(html);
    }
  }
})
```

Where it's being used:

```
// inside of ng-repeat
<div ng-if="someBool">
    Published a snippet 
    <span class="eva-event-snipContent" content="{{ event._chirp._comments[0].content }}" hashfinder></span>
 </div>
```

**Addition @ 4:12pm**

Using @softvar's answer, I got this error:

Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that the `sref-url` element is not compiled. Basically you need to compile the HTML string and then append that.

```
.directive('hashfinder', function($compile) {
return {
restrict: 'A',
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
  var content = $attrs.content;

  var html = content.replace(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig, function(match, p1, p2, offset) {
    var id = "r" + Math.random();

    // Here: ui-sref doesn't work.
    return p1 + '<a href="#" ui-sref="app.lounge" class="eva-hash-highlight2">' + p2 + '</a>';
  });

  $element.html($compile(angular.element(html))($scope).html());
}
```

}
})

Comment: Doing it now. I just wanted to answer it quickly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to compile the HTML string, since it's updated outside the angulars' scope. Use `$compile` service for that.

```
.directive('hashfinder', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var content = $attrs.content;

      var html = content.replace(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig, function(match, p1, p2, offset) {
        var id = "r" + Math.random();

        // Here: ui-sref doesn't work.
        return p1 + '<a href="#" ui-sref="app.lounge" class="eva-hash-highlight2">' + p2 + '</a>';
      });
       $element.html($compile(angular.element(html))($scope));
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Using the code in the answer, I got an error in the console: [link to error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/jqLite/nosel)